# input output redirection in shell c

Tags: c, linux, shell, io

I implement a simple shell. I want to use input/ output redirection. I write some piece of code but my code doesn't work. here is my code :

Comment: firstly, *args[i] == '>'  ---> this doesn't work . I write a printf to try the if statement is right or not  @cad

Comment: can you provide the complete code ?

Comment: your brackets and codeforatting is completely bad...please fix it

Comment: I fix my code @MayukhSarkar

Comment: show the complete to so that we can understand it better..

Comment: Ok. I will update my code and now you can see whole code @MayukhSarkar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97062/discussion-between-mayukh-sarkar-and-esrtr).

Comment: You should learn to use `strtok()` to split the input string, instead of examining every character.

Answer (score 2):

You're duplicating the FD into FD 0, which is `stdin`. `stdout` is FD 1. You should also use `dup2`, so you can specify explicitly which FD to assign to, and the macro that holds the FD.

```
dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
```

You should also change

```
if (*args[i] == '>')
```

to

```
if (strcmp(args[i], ">") == 0)
```

Otherwise it matches any argument that begins with `>`, even if it has other characters after it.

Comment: I apply your solution. There is no error now. Thanks for that. But still I can create a file usin'>' but I can't write anything on that file .

Answer (score 1):

(get used writing `%s\n` in your printf statements)

When your compiled program is called myshell, you will see the > when it is given as an argument:

```
./myshell arg1 arg2 ">" arg4
```

When you don't quote the `>`, the shell will take care of the redirection:

```
# Not what you want:
./myshell arg1 arg2 > arg4
```

would result in myshell being called with parameters arg1 and arg2, and the result of myshell will be redirected to arg4.

Comment: can you explain how can I fix this compare if statement

Comment: @esrtr you need to use `">"` instead of  `>` to avoid shell's default redirection

Comment: @Walter A ... Your solution is based on the fact that OP's system is Linux & Unix based however it is platform independent solution

Comment: I can create a file but I can't writing anything on that file. Why ?

Comment: I don't think he's getting the argument from the shell, the user is typing them into his program and it's splitting them into the `args[]` array.

Comment: For the c-code: try to give a small C-program reproducing your problem.
When you want to test something with redirection (without the trick with quotes), you should open your program myshell without arguments, print a prompt (different from normal, maybe `;-> `) and read a commandline from stdin.

Answer (score -2):

i think that u do not need asterisk* in your If condition.
You want to to compare value of args[x] with a sign '>'.

In case it's not it, Can you write little more about the error which occurs?

Comment: if I don't add * ,it would be an error on terminal : "warning : comparison betwween pointer and integer"

Comment: @Dominik `args[i]` will be a the address...you need to de-reference it to get the value...hence you need that

Comment: how is that? we do not know what kind of array args is from that piece of code but in general u can make reference to the value of an array element without *.

Comment: Check properly he is comparing '>' which is a `char` or `int` type data and hence for `argv`, you need to dereference it twice to get a character because it is array of `char*`..

Comment: oh fine, that args must be main's parameter **char typically called argv. i haven't understood that properly. thanks.

Comment: However to compare a string, you cannot do `argv[i] == "A"` need to use `strncmp`

Comment: well, but there is no string comparison, just 2 chars-> single quotes ' ' says that. : )

Comment: this is my args declaration : char *args[size]; @DominikLach